# Graph API and custom actions

Tags: graph, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

I know It is already possible to get all actions for custom app actions and objects:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/{appNameSpace}:{action}/{object}`

This will list all the actions generated by an app, but only for a given user.

How do I get all the actions generated by an app (for all its users)?

Comment: alredy asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007724/how-to-get-all-the-open-graph-beta-actions-generated-by-an-app/8673285

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007724/how-to-get-all-the-open-graph-beta-actions-generated-by-an-app/8673285

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a list of all actions published by your app using the API. Instead, you should record them yourself when the action is sent to Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

But you could access the actions of your friends and eventually beyond

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=app_namespace:app_customaction&access_token=...
```