# FQL to get user's open graph video.watches activity

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

What table is needed in the FQL to get all of a user's video.watches activity?  I can find no documentation about what table this information is stored in.  An example would also be helpful.

Comment: I hardly believe Facebook provides such information via FQL or Graph API...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This data is not available via FQL, it is currently only available via the Graph API.

Once you have the user_actions.video and/or friends_actions.video you access the watch activity via the `/video.watches` endpoint. For example, if you have the `user_actions.video` permission for the user and want to get their watch activity, you would pass in the access token to the `/me/video.watches` endpoint to retrieve the user's watches.

Relevant documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/read/

Comment: This is for user actions that application published (if "all activity" means activity within application than this is the right answer).

Comment: Actually it's a little more complicated than that. Since read/watch/listen are within the global namespace, any "watch" activity from any app that is publishing actions can be retrieved via this call. Users own their actions that they can share with other apps. Note on the documentation site the bit about "Built In Verticals"

Comment: what would be the best way to get all of a user's friends' watches activity?

Comment: also, can you request these permissions using authenticated referrals?  the box does not seem to let me input these.