# Get Open Graph action ID from authenticated user

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm taking a first shot at the Facebook Open Graph API. I've made a custom Action Type and Object Type. For this question I'll name them "myaction" and "myobject".

```
function postAction(){
    FB.api(
        '/me/appnamespace:myaction?myobject=http://domain.com/page.php',
        'post',
        function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error: ' + response.error.type + ' - ' + response.error.message);
            } else {
                //alert('Like was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
                var likedId = response.id;
                alert('Action was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id + ' (var = ' + likedId + ')');
            }
        }
    );
}
```

This works. The action is published to the user's timeline.

But if that user wants to delete that action (or multiple actions) from my site in a different session? Is there a way to query the custom actions from the user and display them? I could work with a database, and store the actionId, but that will conflict when the user has already deleted the action on facebook

The code for deleting the action would be:

```
function deleteAction(){
    FB.api(
        'xxxxxxxxxx',  // Here the Action ID must be inserted
        'delete',
        function(response) {
            alert('action deleted')
        }
    );
}
```

**Edit:**

This works for getting the action from a specific page (object):

```
function getAction(){
    FB.api(
        '/me/appnamespace:myaction?myobject=http://domain.com/page.php',
        'get',
        function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error: ' + response.error.type + ' - ' + response.error.message);
                console.log(response);
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

This works for getting all the custom actions from the user:

```
function getAllAction(){
    FB.api(
        '/me/appnamespace:myaction',
        'get',
        function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error: ' + response.error.type + ' - ' + response.error.message);
                console.log(response);
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

In short, is there a way to do this in FQL:

- query the Object ID from the current url?
- query the Action ID from the user (all custom Actions and/or specific action based on the Object ID)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Am I the only one who is trying to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data is not available via FQL, it is currently only available via the Graph API. Hope it will present soon.

See this questions:

1. [FQL to get user's open graph video.watches activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499297/fql-to-get-users-open-graph-video-watches-activity)
2. [How to get all the Open Graph Beta actions generated by an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007724/how-to-get-all-the-open-graph-beta-actions-generated-by-an-app)

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. Now I can stop trying to get the info out of the FQL :)