# is there a way to see actions associated with a open graph object?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've got a custom open graph action which connects a user to an open graph object.

Is it possible (using the facebook api) to:

1) Given a user and an object -- see if a connection exists between the two?

2) Look at all connections to the given object

Maybe with FQL or something?

Answer (score 0):

Given an action type and a user you could inspect all the actions done by that user

```
/USER_ID/namespace:action
```

This returns a set of actions based on this type.

If you are referring to the meta object defined in your page then there is no way currently to query this object from within FQL other than this

```
 SELECT url, id, type, site FROM object_url WHERE id = object_id
```

Which doesn't really help as there is no way to list objects associated with a user either

Comment: thats kinda what this post says also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007724/how-to-get-all-the-open-graph-beta-actions-generated-by-an-app   :(